# Function that transforms prime factorization to a sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We define function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ like this: $f(1)=1$ and if $n$ is a natural number greater than $1$ and $$\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\alpha_i} $$is the prime factorization of $n$,$$f(n)=p_1 \alpha_1+p_2 \alpha_2+ \dots+ p_k \alpha_k.$$If $n>6$, prove that $8$ appears in the sequence$$n, f(n), f(f(n)), ....$$ I have no idea how to attack this problem. I tried some of the values of $n$ with a computer and for $n=105$, $8$ appears in the sequence.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then $f(n)=n$ by definition. So its not necessary for $8$ to occur in the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false: $f(p)=p$ for any prime $p$.  For example, $7>6$ and $f(7)=7$.

Comment: I think the statement of problem is not right. It should've been like this: Prove that exists a number $n>6$ such that...

Comment: Hmm, the problem becomes trivial, in that case.  Then $n=8$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @Zilliput $8=2^3\implies f(8)=6$. But $15=3\times5\implies f(1)=8$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I agree, but I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.  The number $8$ certainly appears in the sequence $8, f(8), f(f(8)), \ldots$.

Comment: You are right. I did not take into account the first term in the sequence of iterations.